# Dependency injection with default parameter

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, move

I have a piece of code which is required to use dependency injection and looks like the following:

```
class MyClass {
    IMyDependency &dependency;
public:
    MyClass(IMyDependency &myDependency) : dependency(myDependency) {}
}
```

`IMyDependency` always has an implementation with the name `MyDependency`. I want to be able to provide an object of type `MyDependency` as a default parameter to the constructor, however the I'm not sure how I can marshal the lifetime of this object into `MyClass` via this codepath. I've tried to `std::move` the default parameter but this does not compile. Does anyone have a suggestion here?

Comment: what is the default argument?

Comment: Default construction of `MyClass`

Comment: i meant: What is `dependency` on default construction of `MyClass` ?